# Red Dead Redemption 2 on PC Flash to Desktop Bug

Tags: windows-10, red-dead-redemption-2, red-dead-online

I'm experiencing the same issue as shown in this short video:

If you don't watch the video, what is happening is RDR2 will randomly loose focus and flash back to the Windows desktop for a second and back to RDR2.

Running it on a PC. I've tried different displays (fullscreen, windowed, etc). I've turned off all notifications inside Windows 10.

It randomly happens. If I had to say around 1-2 times an hour.

Anyone else run into this and have figured out how to solve it?

Comment: I notice this happen to me when I tried using the Vulkan API for Graphics.  I don't think it ever happened using Direct X.  The only other thing I thought it could also be was using a controller to play the game (which I did).

Answer (score 2):

This problem is likely because some app is stealing focus from the game.

In some cases, this can be solved by using Fullscreen mode or Borderless Fullscreen (also known as Borderless Windowed, Windowed Fullscreen, or similar). Unfortunately, it seems neither worked for you.

I used to have a similar issue with a different game (Metro Exodus). The game would automatically minimize whenever it lost focus.

To find out why my game kept losing focus, I wrote an app to keep track of any app that receives focus, then I let it run while playing the game until it minimized. The culprit turned out to be an RGB LED control software (Gigabyte RGB Fusion), which would regularly steal focus for no obvious reason.

You can find the app on [GitHub](https://github.com/Nolonar/FocusTest). Scroll down for the README. It contains a download link for the app, as well as the .NET Core Desktop Runtime, which is needed to run the app. Windows will try to stop the app from running when you launch it the first time after downloading. This is normal, as it's an unsigned app. Simply click on "More info", then "Run anyway".

Uninstalling whatever software is responsible for stealing focus should fix your issue. If you can't or don't want to remove it, you could also turn it off while playing Red Dead Redemption 2, as well as any other game where the focus stealing leads to annoying behavior.